# What lightweight cryptographic hash function for short input could I use for HMAC?

Tags: hash, hmac, lightweight

I am looking for a cryptographic hash function that I can configure for HMAC. The input that I will hash is around 50 bytes. The function must be fast, and computationally lightweight.

Comment: I would not use HMAC for short input, since it has at least one block of overhead.

Comment: Is your key fixed (i.e. can you pre-compute the state of the hash function after consuming the key)? What security properties to you require? What output size to do you need? What CPU are you using?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I will use programmable hardware. Up to 64 bytes solutions are okay for output. I do not need more. I can make use of shorter than 64 byte outputs as well. I do not understand your question about the fixed key. Can you please collaborate on this?

Comment: Many hash function need time to process the key. So if you can cache the output of that step, it becomes much cheaper.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I can cache the key yes.

Comment: What security properties do you need / what are you using it for?

Comment: @NinjaBug Do you possibly mean 64 bit of output instead of 64 bytes? HMAC-SHA-512 has 64 byte output, but that would be overkill.

Comment: What is your budget, in CPU cycles, and what kind of machine are you executing on?  Why HMAC in particular, and not some cheaper PRF like Siphash or Kravatte?